# Vertical Division in a Material Design Lite Card

Tags: html, css, material-design-lite

I am using Material Design Lite [Website Link Here](http://www.getmdl.io/)

There is no way whatsoever to make a vertical division in card as per documentation given there.

For Divisions generally grid layout is used in material design but when I am making use of grid then there is by default a space between the two cells. Is there any other way by which I can have vertical divisions without space in a card?

[Demo Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sAgMKE6crE2HDod0iGjY?p=preview)

Css

```
    .grid-handler {
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="grid-handler mdl-grid">
         <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">6</div>
         <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">6</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: add `margin:0;` to both the cell.

Comment: Works mate. @KalpeshSingh Thanks

Comment: I was doing that on the complete grid and hence it wasn't working, my bad.

Comment: No problem man. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `mdl-grid--no-spacing` class with `mdl-grid` :

```
<div class="mdl-grid mdl-grid--no-spacing">
     <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">6</div>
     <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">6</div>
</div>
```